# AddSpacer have weird color

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I'm newbie to building GUI with Python. I'm building an app that receive data from COM port and display it on the graph. Everything is almost finish and I want to have some more space between the graph and the sliders but when I use AddSpacer, they have different color and look pretty awkward. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QTZ0.png)

Below is the code of the program with random data so you can try with your own computer. Any help is much appreciate, thanks!

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# simple.py

import wx
import serial
import time
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from collections import deque
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

########################################################################
class SerialCom():

    def __init__(self,port,b_rate):
        self.port = port
        self.b_rate = b_rate
        global ser
        ser = serial.Serial()

    def connect(self): #Start connect
        try:
            ser.port = self.port 
            ser.baudrate = self.b_rate 
            ser.timeout=1
            ser.write_timeout = 1
            ser.open()
            return('Connecting...')
        except serial.SerialException:
            return("No serial port found")
        time.sleep(1) #Waiting for connection to initialize

    def status(self):
        x=os.path.exists(self.port)
        if x==1:
            return 'Connected'
        else:
            return 'Disconnected'

    def disconnect(self):
        return('Disconnecting')
        ser.close()
class DataGen(object):
    """ A silly class that generates pseudo-random data for
        display in the plot.
    """
    def __init__(self, init=50):
        self.data = self.init = init

    def next(self):
        self._recalc_data()
        return self.data

    def _recalc_data(self):
        delta = random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5)
        r = random.random()

        if r > 0.9:
            self.data += delta * 15
        elif r > 0.8: 
            # attraction to the initial value
            delta += (0.5 if self.init > self.data else -0.5)
            self.data += delta
        else:
            self.data += delta

########################################################################
class TopPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.datagen = DataGen()
        self.data = [DataGen().next()]
        self.paused = False

        self.InitGraph()

        self.redraw_timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_redraw_timer, self.redraw_timer)        
        self.redraw_timer.Start(50)

    def InitGraph(self):
        # init graph
        self.figure = Figure(dpi = 100)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        #set bg, x, y color
        self.ax.set_title('Very important random data', size=14)
        self.ax.grid(True, color='gray')
        self.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND)
        #self.sizer.AddSpacer(10)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        #self.vals = deque()
        self.plot_data, = self.ax.plot([], [])
        self.Fit()
    def update_graph(self):
        xmax = len(self.data) if len(self.data) > 50 else 50
        xmin = xmax - 50
        ymin = round(min(self.data), 0) - 1
        ymax = round(max(self.data), 0) + 1


        self.ax.set_xbound(lower=xmin, upper=xmax)
        self.ax.set_ybound(lower=ymin, upper=ymax)

        self.ax.grid(True, color='gray')        

        self.plot_data.set_data(np.arange(len(self.data)),np.array(self.data))
        self.canvas.draw()

    def on_redraw_timer(self, e):
        #data = float(random.randint(1, 50))
        #self.vals.append(data)
            # update plot data
        #length = len(self.vals)
        self.data.append(self.datagen.next())
        self.update_graph()


########################################################################
class BottomPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent = parent)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 6)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, 1)
        self.timer.Start(1000)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)

        #Create Sliders
        self.Psld = wx.Slider(self, value=200, minValue=150, maxValue=500, style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL)
        self.Isld = wx.Slider(self, value=200, minValue=150, maxValue=500, style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL)
        self.Dsld = wx.Slider(self, value=200, minValue=150, maxValue=500, style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.Psld, pos=(0, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        sizer.Add(self.Isld, pos=(1, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        sizer.Add(self.Dsld, pos=(2, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=10)

        #SliderLabels
        Ptxt = wx.StaticText(self, label="P Term")
        Itxt = wx.StaticText(self, label="I Term")
        Dtxt = wx.StaticText(self, label="D Term")
        sizer.Add(Ptxt, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        sizer.Add(Itxt, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        sizer.Add(Dtxt, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=10)

        #Slider Value
        self.Pval = wx.StaticText(self, label='200')
        self.Ival = wx.StaticText(self, label='200')
        self.Dval = wx.StaticText(self, label='200')
        sizer.Add(self.Pval, pos=(0, 4), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        sizer.Add(self.Ival, pos=(1, 4), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        sizer.Add(self.Dval, pos=(2, 4), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=10)

        #Slider Event
        self.Psld.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnSliderScroll)
        self.Isld.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnSliderScroll)
        self.Dsld.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnSliderScroll)

        st1 = wx.StaticText(self, label='COM port: ')
        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        connect_btn = wx.Button(self, label='Enter')
        sizer.Add(st1, pos=(0, 5), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=12)
        sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl, pos=(1, 5), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border=5)
        sizer.Add(connect_btn, pos=(2, 5), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, border=5)
        connect_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPress)

        sizer.AddGrowableCol(1)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnSliderScroll(self, e):

        valP = self.Psld.GetValue()
        valI = self.Isld.GetValue()
        valD = self.Dsld.GetValue()

        self.Pval.SetLabel(str(valP))
        self.Ival.SetLabel(str(valI))
        self.Dval.SetLabel(str(valD))

    def OnPress(self,e):
        global Ser
        global statusbar
        com = self.text_ctrl.GetValue()
        if not com:
            statusbar.SetStatusText("Please enter port!")
        else:
            Ser = SerialCom(com,115200)
            statusbar.SetStatusText(Ser.connect())
            statusbar.SetStatusText(com, 1)
            time.sleep(1)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        if Ser != None:
            statusbar.SetStatusText(Ser.status())

########################################################################
class GuiFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        super().__init__(parent, title = title, size = (750,550))

        top = TopPanel(self)
        bottom = BottomPanel(self)

        self.SetIcon(wx.Icon("icon2.png"))

        global statusbar

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(top, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        main_sizer.Add(bottom,0, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

        statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(2)
        statusbar.SetStatusText('Disconnected')

########################################################################
statusbar = None
Ser = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GuiFrame(None, title='PID Tuner')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to have an addition main panel on top of top and bot panel.

```py
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('black')
        top = TopPanel(self.panel)
        bottom = BottomPanel(self.panel)

        self.SetIcon(wx.Icon("icon2.png"))

        global statusbar

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(top, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.AddSpacer(40)
        sizer.Add(bottom, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(2)
        statusbar.SetStatusText('Disconnected')
```